# D3 auto updates when array length change

Tags: d3.js

I have simple code here from Interactive Data Visualization by Scott Murray with minor changes. What I changed is the initial data's length `5` is different from the `dataset1`'s length `25` in the `click` function.

However, every time I click and update, it does generate random new numbers but the length only shows 5 bars.

What is the reason for this? And how could I modify to change it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <title>D3  index01 </title>
    <style type="text/css">
    div.bar{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        height: 75px;
        background-color: teal;
        margin-right: 2px;

    }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
    <p> click it </p>

        <script type = "text/javascript">
        var w=600;
        var h = 250;
        var dataset = [5,10,13,14,15];

        var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(d3.range(dataset.length)).rangeRoundBands([0,w],0.05);

        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0,d3.max(dataset)]).range([0,h]);

        var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width",w)
                    .attr("height",h);

        svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(d,i){
                    return xScale(i);
                })
                .attr("y",function(d){return (h-yScale(d));})
                .attr("width",xScale.rangeBand())
                .attr("height",function(d){return yScale(d);});

        svg.selectAll("text")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("text")
               .text(function(d) {
                    return d;
               })
               .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
               .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return xScale(i)+xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
               })
               .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - yScale(d) + 14;
               })
               .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
               .attr("font-size", "11px")
               .attr("fill", "white");

        d3.select("p")
            .on("click",function(){
                var dataset1  = [];
                for(var i=0; i<25; i++){
                    var newNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*25);
                    dataset1.push(newNumber);
                }

                svg.selectAll("rect").data(dataset1)
                .transition()
                .delay(function(d,i){
                    return i*100;
                })
                .duration(500)
                .attr("x",function(d,i){
                    return xScale(i);
                })
                .attr("y",function(d){
                    return h-yScale(d);
                })
                .attr("x", function(d,i){
                    return xScale(i);
                })
                .attr("height",function(d){
                    return yScale(d);
                })
                .attr("fill",function(d){
                    return "rgb(0,0, " + (d*10) + ")";
                });

                svg.selectAll("text").data(dataset1).
                text(function(d) {
                    return d;
                })
                   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                            return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
                })
                   .attr("y", function(d) {
                   return h - yScale(d) + 14;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahh, you create the `rect` objects based of the original dataset. So there will only 5 there to update

Comment: When you `svg.selectAll("rect").data(dataset1)` there are only 5 `rects` that get selected. You see what I'm saying?

Answer (score 0):

The issue, as I see it, is that when you update the `rect`s with the new numbers using this statement

```
svg.selectAll("rect").data(dataset1)
```

the `selectAll` only selects the original 5 `rect`s that were created based on `dataset`

```
var dataset = [5,10,13,14,15];
```

You could either create them all from the start with an equally sized starting `dataset` or append new `rect` svgs at this point.

Since you are doing a transition on the original `rect`s I think it makes the most sense to just start with all 25. You could write a function to automatically generate this and put it where `dataset` is defined:

```
var dataset = [];
var numBars = 25; // This is the number of bars you want
var maxHeight = 25;  // Seems like this is independent and needed as a ceiling
for(var i =0;i < N;i++){
   var newNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()* maxHeight);
   dataset.push(newNumber);
}
```

You could then replace 25 with `numBars` within your `onclick` function as well.